# How to conver switch statement to if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I was wondering if I can convert the following into a if statement rather than it being a switch statement.

```
switch (type) {
  case PROJECT:
  case STORY:
  case DEVELOPER:
    createdItem = new AggregateItem(name, desc, value);
    break;
  case STORY_DEVELOPER:
    createdItem = new SingleItem(name, value, child);
    break;
  default:
    createdItem = null;
}
```

Comment: I don't know, can you?

Comment: `if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

concatinate the first three `switch cases` with `or`.
Then it follows an `else if` and last but not least the `else`.

```
if(PROJECT.equals(type)|| STORY.equals(type) || STORY.equals(DEVELOPER)){
  createdItem = new AggregateItem(name, desc, value);
}else if (STORY_DEVELOPER.equals(type)){
  createdItem = new SingleItem(name, value, child);
}else{
  createdItem = null;
}
```